# Remove an element from an item in a list

Tags: python, arrays

How to remove an element from an item in a list?

normally when I delete something from a list I do:

```
df = [1,2,3,'name']
df.remove('name') #output is [1,2,3]
```

but what if my entry isn't just a regular thing, for example:

```
df = [1,2,3, 'name 123']
```

and I want to get rid of the "_123"?

Comment: do you want to remove 'name 123'  or only 123

Comment: i only want to remove 123. "_123" is "space123"

Comment: Do you know in advance what to remove from which element?

Comment: Please update your question to show what code you have tried in the second case and both the actual output and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to do this. It allows you to seperate out a string into an array using a specified seperator. For instance `"1 4 5 hello".split(" ")` returns `["1", "4", "5", "hello"]`

Therefore, to just obtain `"name"` you could:

```
df[3] = df[3].split(" ")[0]
```

Because `df[3].split(" ")` returns `["name", "123"]`, the 0th index of which is the `"name"` you want.

Comment: But, what if you have a larger list and you are looking to remove that `' 123'` match and don't really know what position you have to replace at? Also, the question provides mixed types, so if while you are iterating you try to call `split` on an int, this won't work.

Comment: If you are certain of what you're looking for, you could always use `df.index()`, then `split()` the array position it returns. Furthermore, if you're worried about calling type on an int, you could check its type, or encapsulate the split operation in a try-except statement.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite catch what you are trying to do, but assuming there is the list you provided us with:

```
df = [1,2,3,'name 123']
```

And you want to remove only the '123' in the specific location, you could do:

```
df[3] = df[3].replace(" 123","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is a list comprehension - something like this:

```
[str(x).replace('123', '') for x in df]
```

(prune '123' off the end of all items).

For more complex pattern matching you may need to use a regular expression.

Comment: For the provided example in the question, this won't work since while you are iterating, a few of the items will actually be integers and `replace` is not an `int` method. Also, I think the space will still be kept in your replacement since you are only removing the `'123'` and not the `' 123'`

Comment: Fixed to `str` x before calling replace - thanks. I was working to the comment on the original question which says 'i only want to remove 123' so yes all other chars (including spaces) will be left.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension combined with `isinstance` is one way:

```
df = [1,2,3, 'name 123']
df2 = [x if not isinstance(x, str) else x.replace(' 123', '') for x in df]

# [1, 2, 3, 'name']
```